# Remove data from MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains data as below in MySQL. `Size` shows file's size in MB.

```
--------------------------------------------
| id  | name | size | user_id | created_at |
--------------------------------------------
| 1   | a    | 120  | 1       | 2017-04-03 |
--------------------------------------------
| 2   | b    | 280  | 1       | 2017-04-04 |
--------------------------------------------
| 3   | c    | 220  | 1       | 2017-04-05 |
--------------------------------------------
```

Now, I want to delete the oldest data if a particular user has crossed the limit of 500MB. In above case, `ID#1` needs to remove.

Can anyone please help me to write a query?

Comment: in your data  size of id 1 is not 500 mb .can you please explain logic

Comment: delete from table_name
where created_at in (select min(created_at) from table_name)

Comment: let's say a user has subscribed for package A which gives user to  1024MB space. Now, for x reason user account got downgraded to FREE package which gives user to 500MB space. So I need to remove files which are older and which are out of space.  #2 and #3 are latest and sum of their size is 500MB. So, we will keep those files

Comment: What if the only entry for id is 500 or more?

Comment: @P.Salmon We need to keep files which are latest and sums of their size are under 500MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a query for that in three steps. First, you get for each user the dates that have files loaded later the 500MB threshold:

```
select  t1.user_id, t1.created_at
from    files t1
join    files t2
on      t1.user_id = t2.user_id and
        t2.created_at > t1.created_at
group by t1.user_id, t1.created_at
having  sum(t2.size) >= 500
```

Then for each user you get the higher of those dates

```
select  user_id, max(created_at)
from    (
            select  t1.user_id, t1.created_at
            from    files t1
            join    files t2
            on      t1.user_id = t2.user_id and
                    t2.created_at > t1.created_at
            group by t1.user_id, t1.created_at
            having  sum(t2.size) >= 500
        )
```

Finally, you use that as reference for the actual `delete`, by joining it with the source table:

```
delete t1
from   yourTable t1
join   (
            select  user_id, max(created_at) as created_at
            from    (
                        select  t1.user_id, t1.created_at
                        from    files t1
                        join    files t2
                        on      t1.user_id = t2.user_id and
                                t2.created_at > t1.created_at
                        group by t1.user_id, t1.created_at
                        having  sum(t2.size) >= 500
                    )
       ) t2
on     t1.user_id = t2.user_id and
       t1.created_at = t2.created_at
```

**Edit**

[Working Rextester](http://rextester.com/VUL73046)

Comment: It only going to remove the first record. There can be multiple records which need to be remove

Comment: Got it, I'll think about a better solution